# JDBC databricks to databricks connection

Tags: python, jdbc, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am looking to connect to a delta lake in one databricks instance from a different databricks instance. I have downloaded the sparksimba jar from the downloads [page](https://databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download?_ga=2.239937283.1044346152.1626165116-1375177589.1620122760). When I use the following code:

```
result = spark.read.format("jdbc").option('user', 'token').option('password', <password>).option('query', query).option("url", <url>).option('driver','com.simba.spark.jdbc42.Driver').load()
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o287.load.: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simba.spark.jdbc42.Driver
```

From reading around it seems I need to register driver-class-path, but I can't find a way where this works.

I have tried the following code, but the bin/pyspark dir does not exist in my databricks env:

```
%sh bin/pyspark --driver-class-path $/dbfs/driver/simbaspark/simbaspark.jar --jars /dbfs/driver/simbaspark/simbaspark.jar
```

I have also tried:

```
java -jar /dbfs/driver/simbaspark/simbaspark.jar
```

but I get this error back: no main manifest attribute, in dbfs/driver/simbaspark/simbaspark

Comment: where do you store your files (dbfs or data lake v1/v2)

Comment: Files are stored in dbfs

Comment: it feels like a better solution would be to move to data lakes

Comment: I work in a corporate and don't have the option to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that (it's really not recommended), then you just need to upload this library to DBFS, and attach it to the [cluster via UI or the init script](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/cluster-libraries.html#cluster-installed-library).  After that it will be available for both driver & executors.

But really, as I understand, your data is stored on the DBFS in the default location (so-called DBFS Root).  But storing data in the DBFS Root isn't recommended, and this is pointed in the documentation:

> Data written to mount point paths (`/mnt`) is stored outside of the DBFS root. Even though the DBFS root is writeable, Databricks **recommends that you store data in mounted object storage rather than in the DBFS root**. **The DBFS root is not intended for production customer data**.

So you need to create a separate storage account or container in existing storage account, and [mount it to the Databricks workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#mount-storage) - this could be done to the multiple workspaces, so you'll solve the problem of data sharing between multiple workspaces.  It's a standard recommendation for Databricks deployments in any cloud.

Comment: Just to confirm, the data is stored in a storage account which is mounted in databricks. I don't have the access to mount that storage location to my other workspace. I have tried uploading the library to the cluster, but this did not work. As it is a driver, I assumed doing this was not the right option.

Comment: it shouldn't matter if it's driver or not.  I really suggest to find a way to mount your storage into another workspace

Comment: If I could do this I would, I work in a company and have no ability to mount this storage account. I am making the best with what I have!

I tried your suggestion but it says 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

I can specify the driver in the statement, but I have tried many variations and it always errors java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example code block that I use (hope it helps)

```
hostURL = "jdbc:mysql://xxxx.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/acme_dbuseSSL=true&requireSL=false"
databaseName = "acme_db"
tableName = "01_dim_customers"
userName = "xxxadmin@xxxmysql"
password = "xxxxxx"


df = (
   spark.read
        .format("jdbc") 
        .option("url", f"{hostURL}") 
        .option("databaseName", f"{databaseName}")
        .option("dbTable", f"{tableName}") 
        .option("user", f"{userName}") 
        .option("password", f"{password}") 
        .option("ssl", True) 
        .load() 
)

display(df)
```

Comment: question is about Databricks to Databricks via JDBC. Not about Databricks to MySQL...